# Get Screen width and fixed it to fixed size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the screen size and if after that the browser gets resized it should not be changed to the new browser width. How I can do that through CSS? Or jQuery?

If I load a web page into my browser and the current screen width is 1000px, after that I resized my web browser which is equivalent to 700px width. But my navbar width should be 1000px; it must not be changed. That is my requirement.

Comment: You cannot reliably disable screen resizing.

Comment: So I cannot do that?

Comment: if it is so then how facebook navbar was created?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [responsive web design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)?

Comment: no i used bootstrap. i disabled it's responsive features. so now i try to get my navbar to 100% width. after that if browser will get resize, my nav bar size should not be changed That is my requirement.

Comment: Is requirement to maintain an element at "100% width" ? , or, width of `viewport` ? Can include `html` , `css` ?

Comment: no, i explain it further, if i load web page into my browser and current screen width is 1000px, after that i resized my web browser which is equivalent to 700px width. but my navbar width should be 1000px; it must not be changed. that is my requirement

Comment: @Top25 `navBarElement.css("width", "1000px")` ?

Comment: yeah that is work. but i want to expand it entire width of the screen. 1000px mean it expand 3/4 of screen width

Comment: Not certain interpret _"but i want to expand it entire width of the screen. **1000px mean it expand 3/4 of screen width**"_  correctly ? "3/4" of initial viewport width , or 100% of initial viewport width ? Can include `html`, `css` at original post ?, create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: 100% of initial viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  $('#navbar').width(windowWidth);
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">Some Content</div>
```

You need to make sure that you set the width of the navbar in pixels of ems. If you set it in percent, then it will always change if the width of its parent (which I'm assuming is the body) is changed. If it's set in pixels or ems, then its width will be static, as long as no code changes it again.

Here's basically what you would need, if the ID of your navbar is `navbar`. I'm setting it in document ready so that it will get set only once, when the navbar is sure to be available, but there might be a better place to set it, depending on your specific circumstances.

Edit: I've added a code snippet that shows that the width of the navbar DOES NOT change when the screen is resized. It is set in the ready event only, and then never changes.

Comment: your method's width change along with viewport width

Answer (score 0):

Try setting parent element `width` to desired width; e.g., `100%` ; setting `nav` width to `width:calc(100%)` .

Could also add a `resize` event to `window` , to maintain width of `nav` at initially loaded viewport width.

```js
$(function() {
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var nav = $("nav");
  
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
     nav.width(width)
  })
  
});
```

```css
body {
  width:100%;
}

nav {
  width:calc(100%);
  height:24px;
  top:0px;
  background:navy;
  color:orange;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<nav>nav</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000) and (min-width:700){
    background-color:red;
}
@media screen and (max-width:699){
    background-color:green;
}
```